# What is Map type "l"?

Tags: texturing, normal-map

for a model of a motorcycle i have got multiple texture/map files for each part. For example for the brakes I have got these three[image]

[image]

[image]

I know that the last one is a normal map but what is the second one? It has an "l" in the file name but I am not sure what this means

Comment: It is most likely an ID map, used in substance to be able to use smart materials

Comment: how do i use it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 3 maps combined to RGB channels.

R:

[image]

G:

[image]

B:

[image]

Maybe bump, roughness and strength for glossy component(would be "IOR Level" in PrincipledBSDF)?

[image]

Just a guess.

Comment: I cant find IOR level

Comment: If you're using Blender version 4+ it's under the Specular dropdown on the latest Principled BSDF shader.

Comment: @Buzzer4246, yep, I assumed you are using current version of Blender because you didn't say otherwise. That's 4.0.2 at this time.

Comment: Yes. I updated Blender now it works. I always lose track of the current version